# Can I know when window.onhashchange is going to be called before the page changes its scroll position?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, fragment, dom-events

If a web page has a link to a fragment (like '#abc') and the user does click on it, `window.onhashchange` is called but I think that the page has already scrolled when it has been called. Am I wrong? I need a way for my code to be informed that the page is going to be scrolled and postpone the scrolling to after some processing has been performed. Is it possible (better without altering the HTML)?

Comment: Yes. You could use an encoded hash fragment that has no corresponding page element, then decide what you really want to do in the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the link element, you just add an `onClick` event that calls a function and returns false, like this:

```
<a href="#container" onClick="testFunction(); return false;">GO TO #container element</a>
```

Note that return false is absolutely necessary in order to stop the page from scrolling to the #container element.

On your testFunction() you can scroll using javascript, like this:

```
function testFunction() {
    // other code
    document.getElementById("container").scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

Or you can use jQuery to smooth scroll to the element:

```
function testFunction() {
    // other code
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top
    }, 500);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use only jQuery to simply add a click listener to your link element, like this:

```
<a href="#container" id="link_element">GO TO #container element</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#link_element').click(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault(); // stops the page from scrolling to the element
            // other code
            // the code for scrolling to the element
        });

    });
</script>
```

I hope this helps you.